# I need to modify and generate IPv6 extended headers

Tags: header, geolocation, ipv6

I want to send from the PC to the server data read by the GPS. I want the coordinates were transferred to one of the fields in the IPv6 header or extension header.

How can I generate such a package?
an application? a driver? programming language? module of the operating system? function of the operating system? windows? linux?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Tranferring GPS coordinates in the IPv6 header (or in the extension header) looks very weird to me. Are you sure you want to do that ?

However, if you use python, [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/introduction.html#about-scapy) is a good tool to generate custom network packets.
[Scapy IPv6 samples](http://www.packetlevel.ch/html/scapy/scapyipv6.html)

Comment: Yes. I must used for the IPv6 header fields

Comment: Why must you use the IPv6 header fields to store something that they are completely unsuitable for?